# Proof of formula for $\pi$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, real-analysis, soft-question, ho.history-overview

The number $\pi$ can be expressed as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\sqrt[n]{-1}-n}{\sqrt{-1}}$ or more poetically $\pi=\frac{\infty\sqrt[\infty]{-1}-\infty}{\sqrt{-1}}$. Here we choose the principal branch of the root. Is there a proof using only roots, without resorting to sines and cosines? (Note: Use of the hyperreals is *not* required.) Does this formula have historical sources? Feel free to use l'Hopital's rule and Taylor formula, too.

Comment: What is this expression even supposed to mean?

Comment: I am not familiar with this fomula. Could you please give a reference, preferably to a source that would explain what it means?

Comment: @Wojowu, if $\infty$ denotes an infinite number, then $\pi$ is the unique real number infinitely close to the righthandside.

Comment: You should specify what arithmetic system of infinite numbers you are dealing with. Also, $\sqrt[n]{-1}$ is ambiguous due to multivaluedness of complex exponentiation.

Comment: @Wojowu, any system satisfying a transfer principle would do.  Here we choose the principal branch of the root.

Comment: I think all of this should be said in the question body so that one doesn't have to ask about this. Either way, I feel like this question doesn't fit on MO.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Hi Todd, is there anything still unclear about my formulation?

Comment: Problems which say that such and such are *not* allowed make me a little nervous. Under Carlo's answer you say you don't want Taylor expansions. What sorts of infinite series are allowed here? What definition of $\pi$ is admissible? May one refer to a solution of a differential equation? It might help me (if no one else) if you were to spell out the requirements formally. (I might try working on this problem if I find some time.)

Answer (score 11):

$$\frac{\infty\sqrt[\infty]{-1}-\infty}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac{1}{i}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(x e^{i \pi/ x}-x\right)=\pi$$

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with this explanation. I think I would have made it even more freshman-like by interpolating $= \frac1{i} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{i\pi h} - 1}{h}$ before the final answer $\pi$.

Comment: At the same time, I imagine the OP has no plans to accept this answer; by mentioning "transfer principle", it seems clear he wants some sort of short nonstandard analysis proof. (Why, I don't know.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I added the comment about transfer because user wojowu asked me to. Since a moderator objects I will redelete it.

Comment: I'm not objecting, @katz -- indeed, I think you ought to amplify even more what you're really after in this question.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I like Carlo's answer but I was hoping for something more elementary that does not involve sines and cosines and taylor expansions. I am thinking about how to reformulate the question but it may soon be too late :-) I seem to have a knack for asking lousy questions that generate popular answers :-) The one about the intended interpretation has been downvoted by a whopping 12 people, while the leading answer has been upvoted by 13 :-)